# finding the original address of the data from a dropdown in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Good day

I am looking for a way to find the address of the data used to create a dropdown in vba. The dropdown is created by using the code :

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="='" & ws.Name & "'!" & range1.Address
```

the dropdown code is used multiple time and I need to find a way to find the worksheet used for the formula1 code. This will help me be able to create cases that reference that worksheet later on in my code.
please see picture attached:

Choosing the selected a or b value is then run by the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J9:J15")) Is Nothing Then
Select Case Target
    Case "a": hala
    Case "b": toets_my_ws
End Select

End If
```

when I select one of the macros I need it to find the worksheet of the validated data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited again: I think this would be easier to integrate as a function - if you want to find the source range for your `Target` cell.

For example:

```vb
Dim rngSource As Range
'...
Set rngSource = ListSourceRange(Target)
If Not rngSource Is Nothing then
    rngSource.Parent.Activate  'do something with rngSource...
End If
'...
```

Function:

```vb
'Given a cell, see if it has a validation list, and
'  try to get the source range for the list
Function ListSourceRange(c As Range) As Range
    Dim vType, rng As Range
    On Error Resume Next       'ignore error if no validation
    vType = c.Validation.Type
    On Error GoTo 0            'stop ignoring errors
    
    If vType = 3 Then
        'try to get a source range...
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = Range(c.Validation.Formula1)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    Set ListSourceRange = rng 'source range, or Nothing if no range found
End Function
```

Comment: I have tried to use this code in a macro that checks if the value selected A it should then run this code but it does not seem like anything is happening

Comment: Sorry, just updated to fix some problems. How exactly are you trying to use the code?  You probably need to make some adjustments to fit it into your current code, but you haven't really provided details there...

Comment: Okay so I created 2 macros "hala" and "toets_my_ws"  hala is your code and "toets_my_ws" is just code to select the cell next to the dropdown to see if my selection code works for the dropdown. My macro does select the cell nect to the dropdown if I use "b" as a selection but the hala macro does not run if i choose "a"         
`'If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J9:J15")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target
        Case "a": hala
        Case "b": toets_my_ws
    End Select
    
End If`   is the code i use for the selection in the dropdown

Comment: sorry i am struggling to find a way to show the code in the comments

Comment: You can *edit your question* to add any new information - no need to struggle with trying to post/read code in comments.

Comment: I have added the selection code to the question thank you @tim

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what you want/expect to happen when someone triggers one of those `Case` options?  The source worksheet will be determined by `Target` (ie. the cell with the dropdown) not whether your user selected "a" or "b"

Comment: So basically when a case is triggered for example A . I want to then go fetch data from cells in the worksheet that was used to validate the data ("so what I mean is that I want to be able to get cell data from where the selection for the dropdown was created) is there an easier way to do this? I am creating a lot of dropdowns based of specific sheets and the selection of the dropdown changes a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229061/discussion-between-demorial-and-tim-williams).

Comment: Sorry not a fan of chat.  See my edit above - that should be closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: thank you for your help is it it possible that you can show me an example of how this code works?

Comment: what I mean is I would just like to see how to use the function if a target is selected, functions are completely new to me

Comment: Isn't that what I posted?  I have no idea what you want to do with the list source range when you have it, so I can't really add much to what I posted.  If you need something more complete you'll need to explain what you need it for.

Comment: for now just being able to select the dropdown and it selecting the worksheet that was used to create the dropdown list info would be great. Also where do I paste this code because currently I am using it in my worksheet general. I read that the function can be declared anywhere so I put that in one of my modules

Comment: See my update above for how to select the sheet with the list source.  Yes you can put the function anywhere - a regular module would be fine.

Comment: Okay thank you I have put your example procedure in my procedure called hala, but now when I select case A it says that the Target variable is not defined. Must I rather not use this in a case ? I hope this will be the last question I bother you with thanks

Comment: `Target` is only defined in the `Worksheet_Change` event since it's passed in as a parameter: if you want to use it in another Sub then you need to pass it as an argument. E.g. modify your sub like this `Sub Hana(Target As Range)` and call it like `Hana Target` to pass `Target` to `Hana`

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and help everything works now

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out.