# Excel VBA - Select first item on Data Validation Dropdown List

Tags: excel, vba, list, dropdown

I am trying to get a cell to automatically add in its first value on the Data Validation Dropdown list of that cell. Haven't been able to find anything online yet that seems to work.

This Sub is being activated by a Private Sub when the user puts in information from other parts of the workbook.

I have snipped out the part of my code that should be selecting the first dropdown value and adding it to the cell but it isn't. .Value = 1 doesn't seem right to me...
I am also not able to list the range that this dropdown will be selecting from as this will be dynamic. I have seen multiple examples of "with" statements being used but it appears they need the range that this list will be working from to operate.

I should mention that the cell, "LastProject" already contains a dropdown list.

Anyone have a better idea?

```
Dim LastProject As Range
    Set LastProject = FoundBMR.Offset(0, 1)

'''Find Last Project Produced for unit
    ''' Function ListSourceRange Required.
    Dim rngSource As Range
        
    rngSource = LastProject
        
    Set rngSource = ListSourceRange(Target)
        If Not rngSource Is Nothing Then
            rngSource.Parent.Activate
        End If
    
    With LastProject
        .ClearContents
        .Validation.Delete
        .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="+" & rngSource
        .Value = rngSource.Cells(1, 1).Value
    End With

Function ListSourceRange(c As Range) As Range
    Dim vType, rng As Range
    On Error Resume Next       'ignore error if no validation
    vType = c.Validation.Type
    On Error GoTo 0            'stop ignoring errors
    
    If vType = 3 Then
        'try to get a source range...
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = Range(c.Validation.Formula1)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    Set ListSourceRange = rng 'source range, or Nothing if no range found
End Function
```

Comment: Are your drop-downs true Data Validation >> List, or some other type of implementation ?  `DropDowns` isn't related to Data Validation - those would be Forms controls added from the Developer ribbon tab.

Comment: If you want to pick the first value from the list source range then you could use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66323724/finding-the-original-address-of-the-data-from-a-dropdown-in-vba/66324010#66324010

Comment: This may be of interest - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525859/how-to-select-a-dropdown-cell-validation-value/65153453#65153453

Comment: @TimWilliams and kevin9999 genius thinking! That's such a great idea.   However, I am getting a Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch on the Set rngSource = ListSourceRange(Target).       Not sure why this is happening.     I have modified the code in the original posting as I am having issues doing it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

More like this, though I'm not sure what you're doing with the validation list here?  Why remove and then re-add?

EDIT: tested and works for me

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim c As Range, rngList As Range
    
    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'has a list-based validation
    
    Set rngList = ListSourceRange(c)
    
    If Not rngList Is Nothing Then
        c.Value = rngList.Cells(1).Value
    End If
    
End Sub


'Given a cell, see if it has a validation list, and
'  try to get the source range for the list
Function ListSourceRange(c As Range) As Range
    Dim vType, rng As Range
    On Error Resume Next       'ignore error if no validation
    vType = c.Validation.Type
    On Error GoTo 0            'stop ignoring errors
    
    If vType = 3 Then
        'try to get a source range...
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = Range(c.Validation.Formula1)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    Set ListSourceRange = rng 'source range, or Nothing if no range found
End Function
```

Comment: Hey @Tim, this code seems to work. However, it is not selecting the first item in the drop down list.     I thought based on the other codes I had been looking at the contents and any previous validations should be removed.

Comment: See my edit above  - that works for me so if you're seeing something different you'll need to do a bit of debugging.

Comment: Hey @Tim, just got back to this. I can confirm your code works, just tired it in a new workbook without any issues.    I tired modifying my code with no luck. I even copy and pasted exactly what you have written above and changed the range to the selected dropdown cell and force ran the sub, that didn't work either!  I even made a new blank sheet in my existing work book and did the same test and it wont work.    No clue what I am doing wrong. Is this workbook cursed??

Comment: If you can share your file I will take a look, but otherwise there's not much I can suggest...